# Namespace is muted in referenced .Net project?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have the following project setup which will not compile, because the `Core` token in a test project files namespace seems to be muting the `Core` namespace in the referenced core project.

```cs
Project: MyCompany.Core
         MyCompany.Core.Extensions.cs
Project: MyCompany.Test
         MyCompany.Test.Core.ExtensionsTest.cs
```

I know that it is muting, because other files in the same test project (outside of  MyCompany.Test.Core) that have worked before using the core alias `using Core = MyCompany.Core;` now report that said type does not exist in `Core` after I added the class MyCompany.Test.Core.ExtensionsTest.cs.

This is baffling...I'd like to resolve this error while still maintaining a clean namespace in the test project `MyCompany.Test.Core.ExtensionsTest`. How can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: It's strange to me that the compiler would not take into consideration the qualifier `MyCompany.Test`  for `Core` namespace in the test project, they really are different namespaces and logically should not conflict? Right?

Comment: Probably this isn't the issue..